# Difference between class variable initializers , static initializers of the class, and the field initializers

Tags: java, initializer

i am trying to follow the JVM specs   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2. 
Is frustrating for me to read the unclear specs. So:
What are the differences between:

> - class variable initializers
> - static initializers of the class
> - field initializers

/*
Initalizers
 */

```
class A {

    private static String x = "sfi";  //static field initializer
    private String ifi = "ifi";  //instance field initializer

    static {              //static (block) initalizer ?!
        String y = "sbi";
    }

    {                    //instance (block) initalizer ?! 
        String z = "ibi";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Static members

First you need to understand the difference between **static** and **non-static** fields of a class. A *static field* is not bound to any instance of the class, it is a property of the class (that is the reason why we access them through the class) so in your example you can access `x` from whithin `A` like this: `A.x`. A common example for this is *counting the number of objects a class has*:

```
private static int counter = 0;
public A()
{
    counter++;  
}

// get the instance count 
public static int getCounter() 
{
    return counter;
}
```

This method we would call from somewhere else like this: `A.getCounter()` and we will retrieve the number of objects that have the type `A`.

#### Non-static members

These are variables that are specific to each object (instance) of the class. In your example this is `sfi`. The runtime system guarantees that `sfi` will be available whenever an object of type `A` is created and that it will have a default value of *ifi*, but the difference here is that each object you create will have a member called `sfi` with a default value of *ifi* so each object can later modify it of course.

#### Initializing blocks

They are a feature designed to be used when initialization cannot be done inline (initialization requires more complex logic like a `for` loop or error-checking). Here again we have:

```
static { /* init code ... /* }
```

which is a static initialization block that "can appear anywhere in the class body. The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code" - from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

If, on the other hand, **we want to initialize instance members** but we cannot do it in one line then we can use a block but without the `static` keyword:

```
{
  // init code for instance members
}
```

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I understand all what you explained. The problem is here: " 9.Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block." I don t understand which are which in this sentence. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

Comment: @Alexis It is the difference between '*class* variable initialisers and static initializers *of the class*' and 'field initializers *of the interface*', as interface fields are implicitly static.

Comment: @EJP , you mean "class variable initializers" and "static initializers of the class" are same as "field initializers", just a general term for both? Look at the Example 12.5-2 example : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5 : "This method therefore runs before the field initializers of Test[class] have been executed" Why are they named field initalizers? And not class initalizers?

Comment: @Alexis because in that example `three` is a non-static field which belongs to each `Test` instance, if it would have been a static field then we could call it a class initializer.